# MQTT measurements export to JSON without connection to a broker

Tags: json, parsing, mqtt

in my setup an IoT device is connected to an MQTT broker and publishes measurements. We duplicate this traffic to another PC where we want to perform analytics on the MQTT data. We cannot create a new client to this broker and subscribe to the topics, we just want to implement a sort of sniffer for these messages and extract the measurements as a JSON.

I have experimented with scapy and various python scripts but haven't succeeded. For example, it seems that the mqtt-paho library for python requires a connection to the actual broker, but as I said this is not an option. Any idea how to approach the problem?

Comment: Why can't you just add another client? MQTT Pub/Sub messaging sort of specialises in 1 to many message delivery.

Comment: Otherwise show what you've tried and explain how it's not working and somebody may be able to help you fix it.